# redirect to page.html after chrome extension installs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is my code, but it refuses to complile on the chrome developer dashboard. I have a page called my-page.php on the server

```
 {
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "go.js" ],
      "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls\u003E" ]
   } ],
   "description": "blahhh",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png"
   },
   "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCdw+eIzaqEWfjrzJZ1TFO0/QVxWNdQEMvf4V6xdpZpTfIW3lOPVIJIvA6D4wyv6H+C8KAgbh58JEkqzgEC/1a+r4jGXhbvQk7Ybjj2CMVJBe6jF5Fz0ckPyTlPreFkT13PGwi72lljRZz7680VwY9jjPa7rsjV4hjTt2RRfi3UfwIDAQAB",
   "name": "my plugin",
      "background_page": "mypage.php",
      "permissions": [ "tabs", "*://*/*" ],
   "version": "1.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Chrome now has an onInstalled event.  Most of you reading this probably know this already, but for those who (like me) search SO instead of reading the actual docs, check out:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled

Answer (score 4):

Your background page is to be packaged with the rest of your files. You can't have a background file that is on your server. It's throwing an error because you probably don't have a file called `mypage.php` in the folder for your extension. [Learn about background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html).

There are [no events](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/faq.html#faq-lifecycle-events) that let your extension know when it has been installed, but a simple way to do it, would be to add code like this in your `background` file:

```
if(!localStorage.first){
    chrome.tabs.create({
       url : "http://whatever.com/welcome.html"
    });
    localStorage.first = "true";
}
```

This would work because the background file's code would be executed right after it was installed, and if `localStorage.first` didn't exist already, it would open the tab and set `localStorage.first` to `true`, so that it didn't open the tab the next time the `background` file's code was executed, i.e. when the browser was reopened.

Note that the tab will open if the user clears all `localStorage` as well. This was the only way I could think of, though.

Comment: then how do i redirect the user after the extension installs? or open a new browser tab to a url of my choice?

Comment: do I put that code in background.html in javascript tags or by itself?

Comment: @RuthBarbour In `<script>` tags. As you can see by the file name, it is a normal `HTML` file. Also, remember to add "tabs" under "permissions" in `manifest.json`!

Comment: i have "tabs" in the permission, a background.html file but it still wont open the window after installing the attachment

Comment: Oops. I had an incorrectly place semi-colon. Try the updated code.

Comment: hmmm still wont redirect. It asks for tabs permission. I assume it should open a new window to  http://whatever.com/welcome.html

Comment: It wouldn't ask for tabs permission if you had "tabs" under "permissions"! Anyway, I made a test extension for you. Download it, unzip it, and load the folder through the extensions page (Load unpacked extension). It should open a new tab when it is installed.