# Chrome extension callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to redirect my users when they are installing my chrome extension.

this is the code given by google:

```
    chrome.webstore.install(string url, function successCallback, function failureCallback)
```

But i cant get it to work, it installs the extension, but nothing happens afterwards.

This is what i just tryed:

```
  onclick="chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/migmokkneocggfbfkklboandoijmbnmn',successCallback(e){alert('bitch');};"
```

Can you please help me? i have searched for hours now.

Comment: have you tried just putting a link to the item on the web store?

Answer (score 0):

Add code like this in your background file:

```
if(!localStorage.first){
    chrome.tabs.create({
       url : "http://whatever.com/welcome.html"
    });
    localStorage.first = "true";
}
```

from [redirect to page.html after chrome extension installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553042/redirect-to-page-html-after-chrome-extension-installs)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. For some reason, that signature doesn't accept function references. So you'll have to make a call like:

```
chrome.webstore.install(
    'webstore-path',
    function() {
        console.log('w00t');
    }
);
```

instead of

```
chrome.webstore.install('webstore-path', callbackRef);
```

Hope that helps!